# How to avoid that an <a> with display:block takes whole width?

Tags: html, css, button

I'm creating a button in its own line thanks to `display: block`. But why does it take the whole width? **How to make it take the normal width of the text inside the button instead?**

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
#a { width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: red; }
#b { background-color: blue; display: block; }
```

```html
<div id="a">
<div>This is a button in its own line, thanks to "display: block"</div>
<a id="b">Button</a>
<div>Something else</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is the definition of 'block' behaviour. If you don't want this behaviour then use, probably, `display: inline-block;`, or put the button in an element that constrains its width.

Comment: @omkara there is no need for bootstrap in this case, also OP never mentioned that he intends to use 3rd parties

Comment: You also don't need `width: 100%`  for html, body or a div, as this is the default behaviour for these block-level elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A block element by default takes the full width it's parent.
So, instead, use `inline-block`

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#b {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div>This is a button in its own line, thanks to "display: block"</div>
  <a id="b">Button</a>
  <div>Something else</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But inline-block disables adding element to new line

Answer (score 2):

Give it a `display:inline-block;` and it will behave as you wish.

**Working example**

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#b {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div>This is a button in its own line, thanks to "display: block"</div>
  <a id="b">Button</a>
  <div>Something else</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But inline-block disables adding element to new line